# How to read Samsung Android MessagingContentProvider (SecurityException)

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-permissions, samsung-mobile

I need to directly read

content://com.samsung.android.messaging.service.provider.MessageContentProvider/messages

(Why? Trying to find some way to get to RCS messages, which do not trigger SMS_RECEIVED)

As expected there is a SecurityException

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException:
Permission Denial: opening provider com.samsung.android.messaging.service.provider.MessageContentProvider
from ProcessRecord{c72fe1ad0 14345:com.gearandroid.phoneleashfree/u0a474} (pid=14345, uid=10474)
requires com.samsung.android.messaging.permission.READ_MESSAGE or
com.samsung.android.messaging.permission.WRITE_MESSAGE
at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1966)
```

I added com.samsung.android.messaging.permission.READ_MESSAGE and om.samsung.android.messaging.permission.WRITE_MESSAGE to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.android.messaging.permission.READ_MESSAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.android.messaging.permission.WRITE_MESSAGE"/>
```

But no luck. Thanks for help, suggestions

Comment: If you examine the manifest for that app, you'll see `<permission android:name="com.samsung.android.messaging.permission.READ_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signatureOrSystem"/>`, and similarly for `WRITE_MESSAGE`. That means that normal apps cannot get those permissions.

Comment: One tries and tries :-)